# How to read a .txt as an argument for netbeans

Tags: java, netbeans, text, args

I just finished an assignment for class and uploaded it to a website desgined to give the program the argument when uploaded and run. Since the site just shows your output and the coding goes "behind the scenes" just for the professor to read I cant see it actually running. I was wondering how I woud input an Args.txt file into netbeans so that I may know how to do it and test projects on my own in the future. Here is the output code for my file :

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
 In in = new In(args[0]);
 Graph G = new Graph(in);
 GraphProperties gp = new GraphProperties(G);

 System.out.println("diameter: " + gp.diameter());

System.out.println("radius: " + gp.radius());

System.out.println("center: " + gp.center());
}
```

I tried putting it into properties but didn't get anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is `in`? Is it supposed to be the contents of the file?

Comment: @badjr yes thanks for asking I forgot to mention that the code I posted is just the last part of my main class. My whole package for the assignment consists of about 6 classes, most of which was given to us by the site, In.java being one of them. This is the link to that code: http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/stdlib/In.java.html, it's kind of long but I can paste it if it helps

Comment: What happened when you put Args.txt into the arguments in project properties?

Comment: I get something like this:                                 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0  at GraphProperties.main(GraphPropertied.java:40)  Java Result: 1

Comment: What's on line 40 of GraphPropertied.java?